# $f(x+f(y))=f(x-f(y))+4xf(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions $f:R\rightarrow R$ which satisfy $f(x+f(y))=f(x-f(y))+4xf(y)$ $\forall x,y \in R$.

I strongly suspect $0$ and $x^2+C$  to be the only solutions but, as is almost the case with functional equations, finding the set the solutions is easy; it is proving that a certain set of solutions represents ALL solutions is what is difficult.

It is trivial that if $f$ is bounded $f\equiv0$.

Comment: What is the motivation behind the equation? It looks pretty random...

Comment: Looks like $x^2 + 1$ is also a solution. Of course, I might have screwed up the algebra. I am guessing $x^2 + C$ will also be a solution...

Comment: @Moron You are correct.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: I was given this problem by a friend; it may very well be contrived.

Comment: @bobobinks: One observation is if $z = f(y)$, then $f(2z) = 4z^2 + f(0)$. This can be seen by plugging $x= f(y)$ in the functional equation.

Comment: Further, if we assume $f(x)$ is continuous and $\exists y^*$ such that $f(y^*) = 0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{y \rightarrow y^{*}} \frac{f(x+f(y)) - f(x-f(y))}{2f(y)} = 2x$.Hence $f'(x) = 2x$ which implies $f(x) = x^2 + f(0)$

Comment: @Sivaram: The assumptions I listed are the only assumptions given. However, if you are able to show that $\forall x\in R f(x)=f(-x)$, I will be able to complete the proof.

Comment: @bobobinks: Yes I understand. I am just posting comments which might be of relevance to others to think along these lines to answer the questions.

Comment: @bobobinks isnt that trivial by setting $x=0$ and $f(y) = z$?  Or I guess it depends on the range of $f$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I finally got it: the equation $f(x + f(y)) = f(x - f(y)) + 4xf(y)$ can be rewritten as
$$f(x + f(y)) - f(x - f(y)) = (x + f(y))^2 - (x - f(y))^2$$
Replacing $x$ by $x + f(y)$ and rearranging terms we get
$$f(x + 2f(y)) - (x + 2f(y))^2 = f(x) - x^2$$
Thus $f(x) - x^2$ has period $2f(y)$ for all $y$. In particular, it has period $2f(a + f(b))$ as well as $2f(a - f(b))$ for all $a$ and $b$. Since the difference of two periods is a period, it also has period $2f(a + f(b)) - 2f(a - f(b))$ for any $a$ and $b$, which is $8af(b)$ by the conditions given. Assuming $f(x)$ is not the zero function, we may pick $b$ so that $f(b)$ is not zero. Since $a$ can be anything, we conclude $f(x) - x^2$ has every real number as a period; in other words it is constant. So if $f(x)$ is not the zero function, then $f(x) = x^2 + C$ for some constant $C$.